# Reproducir audio en java en un intervalo de tiempo

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de hace un ***timer*** que reproduce un sonido (este sonido dura 0.5 segundos) cada 5 segundos,  todo esto con ***java*** en desktop  , pero mi problema es que el intervalo se cumple pero aveces falla la reproducion del ***clip*** de audio , a veces reproduce y a veces no, no deja ningun mensaje de error ni nada, gracias de antemano , aquí  el codigo ***java***:

```
 //ruido blanco
         myTimer = new Timer();
        tarea = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Clip sonido = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    System.out.println((i +=1) +" Se carga con un fichero wav");
                    AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("/audio/pip.wav"));

                    sonido.open(audioStream);

                    sonido.start();


              } catch (Exception e) {
                  System.out.println("" + e);
              }
            }
        };  
       myTimer.schedule(tarea, 0,5000);
       //fin ruido blanco
```

Comment: Hola, acabo de probar tu código y la verdad es que no acabo de encontrar el problema. Lo único que me hace pensar en algún problema es la línea de código System.out.println((i +=1) +" Se carga con un fichero wav"); ya que no soy capaz de identificar donde defines la variable i. Podrías subir el resto de código? Gracias.

Comment: Hola , gracias por la respuesta , la variable i es un contador no tiene mayor relevancia lo uso para ver cuando entra una ves mas al intervalor y no reproduce  , intenta esperar a que el intervalo se cumpla mas de  60  veces es posible que encuentres unos mensajes de error. Es raro que a ti  no te  pase y a mi si , intenta compilar el proyecto y lanzar el ejecutable.